# Moving mysql slave

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-replication

I am trying to move MySQL slave from old pc to new. Original slave is MySQL version 5.6.12 same as new slave(MySQL is part of wamp 2.4). Replication works fine at old machine. But when I stop slave, copy data folder and my.ini to new and try to start wamp I get:

```
`2015-12-20 17:07:40 144 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
 2015-12-20 17:07:40 144 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
 2015-12-20 17:07:40 144 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
 2015-12-20 17:07:40 144 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
 2015-12-20 17:07:40 144 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
 2015-12-20 17:07:40 144 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.0G
 2015-12-20 17:07:40 144 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
 2015-12-20 17:07:40 144 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
 2015-12-20 17:07:40 144 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 3737360739086 and 3737360739086 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 3737360743076 in the ib_logfiles!
 2015-12-20 17:07:40 144 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
 2015-12-20 17:07:40 144 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
 2015-12-20 17:07:40 144 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
 2015-12-20 17:07:49 144 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
 2015-12-20 17:07:49 144 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
 InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 191213785, file name .\mysql-bin.000337
 2015-12-20 17:07:52 144 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.12 started; log sequence number 3737360743076
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [ERROR] Aborting

 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Binlog end
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
 2015-12-20 17:07:53 144 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
 2015-12-20 17:07:54 144 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 3737360748271
 2015-12-20 17:07:54 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
 2015-12-20 17:07:54 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
 2015-12-20 17:07:54 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
 2015-12-20 17:07:54 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
 2015-12-20 17:07:54 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
 2015-12-20 17:07:54 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
 2015-12-20 17:07:54 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
 2015-12-20 17:07:54 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
 2015-12-20 17:07:54 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
 2015-12-20 17:07:54 144 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
 2015-12-20 17:07:54 144 [Note]
```

And that all. Running mysqld-debug :

```
2015-12-20 17:26:01 2896 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-12-20 17:26:01 2896 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-12-20 17:26:01 2896 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-12-20 17:26:01 2896 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-12-20 17:26:01 2896 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-12-20 17:26:01 2896 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.0G
2015-12-20 17:26:01 2896 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-12-20 17:26:01 2896 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-12-20 17:26:06 2896 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-12-20 17:26:06 2896 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-12-20 17:26:06 2896 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.12 started; log sequence number 3737360748271
2015-12-20 17:26:06 2896 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3307
2015-12-20 17:26:06 2896 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-12-20 17:26:06 2896 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-12-20 17:26:06 2896 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Then I connect to DB, running query 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS':

```
Slave_IO_STATE:Connecting to master 
LAST_IO_ERRNO:2003
Last_IO_ERROR:error connecting to master 'repl@192.168.1.9:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 5
```

Firewall is turned off, master ip is available (ping works).
I am wondering, what is wrong - regular wamp start service fail with no error number, mysqld-debug can't connect to master.

What can be wrong, when slave runs at original vm without any problem?
Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite log not mentioning it, MySQL missed errmsg.sys file. This was mentioned in windows event viewer. After copying errmsg.sys, everything is ok, slave running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the grants to allow the new slave to connect ?

Comment: user repl can connect from host % and have slave privilege. So I don't need to update them, right?

Comment: Sounds good to me.